# PyPDF2 'PageObject' is not defined

Tags: python, runtime-error, pypdf

I've been using PyPDF2 (version 1.26.0) to create new PDFs with no problems so far: rotating, cropping pages and more.

For some reason, the second line throws an error:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

page = PageObject.createBlankPage(100, 100)
```

Being the error the following:

```
NameError: name 'PageObject' is not defined
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: `PageObject ` needs to be defined from `PdfFileReader `. like `pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)       pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)` and then `pageObj.createBlankPage(100, 100)`

Comment: @UpasanaMittal doing that throws another error:
if pdf is not None and pdf.getNumPages() > 0:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getNumPages'

Comment: if possible, can you post the whole code?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal That is the whole code, just the two lines. I'm checking out the main PyPDF2 file, pdf.py, to see if I can realize what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry. then define `PdfFileWriter` object  not `PdfFileReader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to achieve what I wanted, using PdfFileWriter's "addBlankPage"

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addBlankPage(100, 100)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you aren't importing the PageObject class. Python only has access to the things you import. Please add this to the top of your file:

```
from PyPDF2.pdf import PageObject
```

Comment: Note that this line of code is slightly outdated with regards to current use. [Here in the documentation for PyPDF](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/migration-1-to-2.html#imports-and-modules) it states: "PyPDF2.pdf no longer exists. You can import from PyPDF2 directly". So the line should now be `from PyPDF2 import PageObject`. Otherwise, you get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyPDF2.pdf'`.